# Recursion in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to have a menu where the parent category can have as many child categories. The child categories can have as many sub child categories and so on......

Eg:

- List item:

  - list 1
  - list 2

    - list 2 a
    - list 2 b

      - list 2 b i

any insight for this ???

PS. Using Codeigniter HMVC

Currently I am working by :

Using a helper function...

I can view 2 level nested categories by the following code:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($results as $row){ ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $row->cat_title; ?>
        <?php 
        $childs = get_child_cat_by_id($row->cat_id);
        if(!empty($childs)){ ?>

        <ul>
            <?php  
            foreach($childs as $child){ ?>
            <li><?php echo $child->cat_title; ?>  
                <?php 
                $sub_child = get_sub_childs($child->cat_id);
                if(!empty($sub_child)){ ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php  
                    foreach($sub_child as $children){ ?>
                    <li><?php echo $children->cat_title; ?>  </li>
                    <?php }?>
                </ul>
                <?php } ?>

            </li>
            <?php }?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>

    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

this code is used in the view. i need a recursive method so that the function get_child_cat_by_id need not be called many times.

Comment: Could you provide some details about this? What is your data source, what have you tried, where you got struck... without a specific question, you probably wont get anything useful.

Comment: Hey, just a heads up: CI is not relative to your question.

Comment: i have made changes to the code as needed. the above is the view file. the controller passes the category details such as title and its id and the parent id.

Comment: @RPM what i am saying is I am using CI and am stuck in a point where i need to recurse the get_child_cat_by_id() function ....

Comment: Can you show us what a `print_r()` of the array looks like?

Comment: stdClass Object ( [cat_id] => 6 [cat_title] => main [cat_slug] => main [cat_parent] => 0 [cat_created] => 2013-02-21 16:06:01 )

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have for your problem would be to use an ORM supproting hierarchical data like [Doctrine 2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/hierarchical-data.html) or [Rapid Data Mapper](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/138360/) with the nested set extention

But a simpler solution would be to get a nested array of your data (deal with your model for that) and try something like:

```
//Make a list from an array 
function nestedArrayToList($array, $property)
{
    $output = '<ul>';

    foreach ($array as $key => $mixedValue) { 
        if (is_array($mixedValue)) {
            // Recursive step
            $output .= '<li>' . nestedArrayToList($mixedValue) . '</li>'; 
        } else {
            // Simply output the property
            $output .= '<li>' . $mixedValue->$property . '</li>'; 
        }
    } 

    $output .= '</ul>'; 

    return $output; 
}


nestedArrayToList($row)
```

I did not tested it, but the idea is here.